# Passing Vue data into Ejs include()

Tags: html, vue.js, ejs

Look please

```
<div v-for="food in foods">
        <%- include('../partials/navbar', {food:food}); %>
</div>
```

Here I'm trying to pass food from foods array using Vue into Ejs include() function. Does anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use component instead:

```
<navbar v-bind='food' />
```

More about props:
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html
More about components
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html